# as3 What' the difference between call matrix.scale() and directly set scaleX and scaleY

Tags: actionscript-3, matrix

Why not the same result on the two code blocks below?

use matrix.scale()

```
const sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
const matrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
sprite.transform.matrix = matrix;

matrix.translate(100, 50);
matrix.scale(2, 1);
sprite.transform.matrix = matrix;
trace(sprite.transform.matrix.toString());
```

set sprite.scaleX

```
const sprite:Sprite = new Sprite;
const matrix:Matrix = new Matrix;
sprite.transform.matrix = matrix;

matrix.translate(100, 50);
sprite.transform.matrix = matrix;
sprite.scaleX = 2;
trace(sprite.transform.matrix.toString());
```

Comment: If call matrix.scale(), it use the matrix multiplication, i do the calculation, it's be identical with the result. But why the sprite.scaleX has the different performance.

Comment: Very likely because the `Sprite` you are scaling is empty. Add something to the `Sprite` so that it has a width and do your experiment again.

Comment: The results are still different. matrix.scale(2, 1) will change both the tx and the a, but sprite.scaleX=2 only change the a.

Answer (score 0):

I have a idea.

```
trace(sprite.transform.matrix == sprite.transform.matrix);
```

The result is false. It means sprite will compose the matrix while getting it.

It may compose such as below.

```
matrix.createBox(sprite.scaleX, sprite.scaleY, sprite.rotation, sprite.x, sprite.y);
```

That does scale first, then rotate, at last translate.
It's different.